# Twitter API: Detecting, managing, and ending sessions

Tags: php, session, twitter, twitter-oauth

At the moment, I am looking to offer a page to users to manage multiple social network accounts.  These can include multiples of each service type.  I am having a difficult time understanding how to detect if a user is logged into twitter(in order to prompt them to log in), manage multiple twitter accounts for a single user (say a business has multiple branches), and the like.

Now, I can already get the token credentials, so I can connect to the API.  I guess my real question is:

Is there a documented process for managing twitter accounts through the API?

Facebook has a pretty easy process that checks for an existing user on pageload.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by **managing**? You can update the authenticating user's settings by [POST account/settings](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/account/settings), update the authenticating user's profile image by [POST account/update_profile_image](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/account/update_profile_image) and a plenty of other actions which you can find [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) in the **Users** section.

Comment: I guess to be more specific-

Managing which accounts are:

    1) Signed into twitter (to prompt login)
    2) Authorized my app 

Since I posted this, I have written a function to determine if the application has an access token for a given user.  According to the API documentation, the access tokens do not expire, but a user can revoke the token.  So that leads me to assume that I should also write a function to check if the access token is valid each time. 

I believe I can use:  

get('account/verify_credentials')

Comment: So, your problem is authentication and authorization? OK, you can find out all the information on this topic here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth And yes, to check validity of your token, you should use *GET account/verify_credentials*